# Начинаю разбираться с MVC - какой подход будет правильным?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Начну с того, что я новичок, сделал всего один небольшой проектик на php "процедурным" способом и теперь ищу способ, чтобы перепрыгнуть огромную пропасть, отделяющую процедурное программирование от ООП. Большая часть инфы по MVC предусматривает, что я уже перебрался через эту пропасть, и оттого практически бесполезна. Нашёл пока [единственную статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/), которая максимально примитивно объясняет, начиная с основ, и пытаюсь по аналогии свой проектик переделать под MVC.

Возникла проблема - в моём проекте логика чуть посложнее, чем в "сайте-визитке", и статья не даёт ответа на вопрос, где и как это "посложнее" реализовать.

В упомянутой статье класс `View` крайне прост: метод `View->Generate($view_content, $view_template)` делает `require $view_template.'.php'`, внутри шаблона в свою очередь в единственном месте стоит `require $view_content.'.php'`.

У меня, в зависимости от контроллера/метода, необходимо делать вставки в шаблон в нескольких местах. **Вопрос - как реализовать это правильно?**

Предполагаемый мной вариант решения: в главный шаблон напихать конструкции вида `include $block[0].'.php'` (не `require`, чтобы не ругался при отсутствии файла), потом этот массив заполнять именами файлов в соотв. модели...

Сразу возникают вопросы:

1. если мне в данном view не нужно вставлять скажем `$block[0]` - как будет выполняться директива `include`? Будет ли она пытаться обращаться в файлу (в данном случае `NULL`)? Да и вообще, правильно ли так поступать? (**upd:** вариант конечно `if (isset($block[0])) { include $block[0].'.php'; }` - но это получается часть логики переносится в вид :/ )
2. как быть с блоками, которые хочется задействовать несколько раз? Например, у меня там простенькая формочка для фильтрации вывода с базы, но на одной странице она должна фильтровать поставщиков, а на другой - товар на складе?
   Реализовывать формочку через класс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте что такое виджеты и зачем они. Если вкратце то это независимое обращение к любому модулю вашего сайта, допустим модуль отзывов. Вы вызываете виджет данного модуля, и все инкампсулировано внутри него, он сам определяет на какой он странице (или в параметре передаете), знает к какой модели обратится, и как вывести данные в шаблон. Очень удобны и незаменимы.

Издалека ваш подход правильный, но я бы реализовывал массив по типу

```
$content = array(
    'header' => 'Hellow world',
    'short_description' => 'short description of page',
    'footer_links' => array(
        0 => array('name' => 'main page', 'link' => 'http://...'),
        ....
    ),
);
```

и этот контент передаю непосредственно шаблону, темплейту.
Где использую его так:

```
<?php
if (isset($content['header']) && !empty($content['header'])){ ?>
    <h1><?=$content['header']?></h1>
<?}
```

и так далее.